# Why can't I use the Chinese input method to use the google doc "@" smart box?

Tags: google-docs

When I use the English input method, it works fine to type "@" to call out a smart box, such as a file or document.

But when I use Chinese input method, everything changed, it's like a magic wand that lost its magic, it's just "@", not "@" that can call out powerful magic.

So, please help.

I just switched the input method and typed "@", then realized that only the English input method works, while the Chinese input method is like ...... Anyway, it doesn't work.

Comment: You would better ask on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Probably because American programmers only test American keyboard layout and Latin script. If this is a programming question of any kind (you're writing macros or extensions for Google Docs), you may want to edit the question and provide more details. If it's an end-user support question, I'm afraid this is not the right site to ask.